# How do you convert an ISO 8601 date to a UNIX timestamp in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I've been trying Time.parse() and Date.parse(), but can't see to figure it out.

I need to convert a date in the form "2007-12-31 23:59:59" to a UNIX timestamp.  Something like PHP's strtotime() function would be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

The ISO 8601 time format for the example you give would be "2007-12-31T23:59:59", not "2007-12-31 23:59:59" (note the `T` between the data and time components).

In Ruby, if you require the `time` library, you can parse properly formatted ISO 8601 dates. If your dates are coming in with a space instead of a `T` to separate the date from the time, just replace it before passing it in to `Time.iso8601`:

```
>> require 'time'
=> true
>> Time.iso8601("2007-12-31 23:59:59".sub(/ /,'T'))
=> Mon Dec 31 23:59:59 -0500 2007
```

To convert a time in this format to a Unix timestamp, just use `.to_i`:

```
>> Time.iso8601("2007-12-31 23:59:59".sub(/ /,'T')).to_i
=> 1199163599
```

If you need more flexibility about the format, `Time.parse` should do the trick; I would be careful about using that in production code, however, because it might give unexpected values for malformed or invalid input, instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 5):

You have [`Time.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Time.html#M000326) in Ruby 1.9 So in your case,

```
>> time = Time.strptime('2007-12-31 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')     
=> 2007-12-31 23:59:59 +0000
```

Once you have a `Time` object, you can convert it to many formats. A simple `time.to_i` will give you a Unix Timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'date.to_time.to_i' to convert date time to unix timestamp.

Following is the output on rails console:-

> > date = Date.today
> >     => Thu, 23 Sep 2010
> >     date
> >     => Thu, 23 Sep 2010
> >     date.to_time.to_i
> >     => 1285180200

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: Well this works in rails. Following is the out put on rails console >> date = Date.today
=> Thu, 23 Sep 2010
>> date
=> Thu, 23 Sep 2010
>> date.to_time.to_i
=> 1285180200

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strftime` method

date = Date.today #this will return Thu, 23 Sep 2010
str_date = date.strftime('%b %d %Y') # This will give Sep 23 2010

refer this for better understanding
[blog](http://rohitsharma9889.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/customizing-the-way-date-and-time-is-represented-in-rails-by-using-strftime-method/)

This will help you to convert time in custom formats. But it won't work in your case i.e converting it to UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out all I needed was:

Time.parse(date_str).to_i